# Case confusion: “der ausgefüllten Dokumente” or “die ausgefüllten Dokumente”

Tags: grammar, grammatical-case, formality, genitive, accusative

I would like to reply to an email in formal context. I have doubts regarding the German counterpart of the English phrase:

> Please find attached the completed documents.

Is the German phrase written below apt and correct in regard to the context?

> Im Anhang finden Sie *die ausgefüllten Dokumente*.

While browsing through some random documents I came across a sentence in which *der ausgefüllten Dokumente* was employed, I was wondering how a neuter noun in plural could be assigned *der* in the concerned sentence. I am aware of the genitive case but I am not able to get hold of the gist!

> Der EUROPASS-Rahmen und die zugehörigen Unterstützungsdienste sollten sich 
>   auf ein geeignetes Informationssystem stützen, das eine koordinierte Verknüpfung *der ausgefüllten Dokumente* und deren 
>   Bereitstellung für die Inhaber im Internet ermöglicht. <sup>([EURLEX 52003PC0796, section 2.5](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=CELEX:52003PC0796%3aDE%3aHTML))</sup>

Comment: General hint: The rule of putting a space before “double punctuation” such as `?!:;` is specific to French. It is neither used in German nor English and looks rather strange here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, *der ausgefüllten Dokumente* is genitive (meaning *of the completed documents*). The sentence is from an EU document, which means that it exists in all official languages of the EU, including [English](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=CELEX:52003PC0796:EN:HTML) and [French](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=CELEX:52003PC0796:FR:HTML):

> The Europass framework and the related support services should rely upon a suitable information system, allowing to link in a coordinated way the completed documents and to make them available to their holders through the Internet.
>
> Le cadre Europass et les services de soutien connexes devraient s'appuyer sur un système d'information adapté, permettant de relier de manière coordonnée les documents complétés et de les mettre à la disposition de leur titulaire par Internet.

---

Regarding the other question, a more common phrase would be:

> Die ausgefüllten Unterlagen habe ich beigefügt.

I think *Unterlagen* (always plural) is better than *Dokument(e)*, which makes it sound like very official documents, such as a birth certificate. If it is actually a form, *das ausgefüllte Formular* would be even better.

Comment: That ought to solve my confusion. And thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Geekasaur: I’ve included the official English and French versions of the sentence you cited.

Comment: Merci bien pour les explications précises :)

Answer (score 2):

In your English original, you are speaking about one document, singular.

If that is what you intend to say, the following is correct:

> Im Anhang finden Sie das ausgefüllte Dokument.

I slightly disagree with chirlu about the usage of "Dokumente" and "Unterlagen", at least in a computer context. Your PDF document is a "Dokument", regardless of whether it contains your CV or a party invitation.

---

chirlu is right about the form of "der Dokumente":

> *noun phrase* (**eine Verküpfung** *genitive attribute* (**der ausgefüllten Dokumente**))

Comment: Thanks! That means the original sentence in my question stands good for completed electronic documents ,right ?

Comment: Sorry , I wanted to say `documents`, corrected now .

Comment: @elena: Admittedly, _Dokument_ is official Microsoft/Adobe terminology, but do you know anyone who says so? I'd say _Word-Datei_ and _PDF_ are the normal expressions.

Comment: elena, I removed the obsolete part about the c&p-error. But you should also notice that the plural/singular issue has been changed in the question as well.

Comment: @Geekasaur: Your translation is correct German. chirlu: Agreed, "Datei" sounds better referring to files. Referring to files as "Unterlagen" seemed unintuitive to me. Em1: Thanks. I'm guessing my answer is getting more obsolete by the minute. ;)